# Linear Algebra Question from Mock GRE exam.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces, and that $f:V\mapsto W$ is a linear map. Suppose $\{e_1,...,e_n\}\subset V$ and that $\{f(e_1),...,f(e_n)\}$ is a basis of $W$. Then which of the following are true?

I. $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ is a basis of $V$

II. There exists a linear map $g:W\mapsto V$ such that $g\circ f=Id_V$

III. There exists a linear map $g:W\mapsto V$ such that $f\circ g=Id_W$

(A) I only

(B) II only

(C) III only

(D) I and III

(E) II and III

---

The solutions manual says it is (B), but I think it should be (C) since we can regard $W$ to be isomorphic to some subspace of $V$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If (C) should be the answer in your opinion, statement II should be wrong. Why would that be the case?

Comment: Let $V$ be $\mathbb{R}^3$, $W$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f$ projection onto the first two factors. Then the assumption of the theorem holds, as does III, but I and II do not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For I, we can exhibit a counterexample. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = a_1$ with $n > 1$. Clearly this is a linear map. Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f(e_1) = 1$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$, yet $e_1$ is not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For II, we can also exhibit a counterexample. Consider the same linear map given in the first counterexample. Suppose there did exist a linear map $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g \circ f = Id_{\mathbb{R}^n}$. Then
$$
(0,1,0 ,\ldots, 0) = e_2 = Id_{\mathbb{R}^n} (e_2) = (g \circ f)(e_2) = g(f(e_2)) = g(0) = (0, \ldots, 0)
$$
which is a contradiction.

For III, we can prove that it must be the case. Suppose $f: V \to W$ is a linear map as in the problem. Take $w \in W$. Then, since $\{f(e_1), \ldots, f(e_n)\}$ is a basis for $W$, there exist $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ such that
$$
w = \sum_i w_i f(e_i) = \sum_i f(w_i e_i) = f\left(\sum_i w_i e_i\right)
$$
Clearly $v \equiv \sum_i w_i e_i \in V$, so we may conclude that there exists $v \in V$ such that $f(v) = w$. In other words, $f$ is a surjective linear map. Since $f$ is surjective, there must exist a linear map $g : W \to V$ such that $f \circ g = Id_W$. (I previously asserted that this fact was trivial to prove, but it really isn't. In fact, I don't know of a way to prove it that doesn't require the axiom of choice! Nevertheless, it is true). This proves III.

To conclude, I'd have to agree that (C) is the right answer.

Comment: Just want to point out that I was able to prove the existence of $g$ without the axiom of choice, but it still isn't what I'd call a trivial proof.

Comment: I don't know if the existence of $g$ is *that* tough. Define $g$ on the set $\{f(e_1),\dots,f(e_n)\}$ by mapping $f(e_i)$ to $e_i$. Extend linearly to yield a linear map $g\colon W \to V$, and then check that the double composition $f\circ g$ is the identity map of $W$.

Comment: That's exactly right. I suppose it's a matter of taste what one calls trivial. I try to avoid using the word trivial if the proof involves any original ideas. The choice to map $f(e_i)$ to $e_i$ and extend linearly is right on the edge for me. In this case I leaned toward calling it non-trivial because you might have the bad idea (like I did) to establish the existence of $g$ (say with the axiom of choice) and then prove that $g$ is linear or that at least one such $g$ is. To put it a different way, I called it non-trivial because I had the wrong idea for the proof at first glance.

Comment: The correct proof (your proof), also caught me a little by surprise. To show the existence of a right inverse for a surjective function, you need the axiom of choice. To show the existence of a linear right inverse for a linear surjective function, which a priori seems like it should be harder than merely finding a right inverse, you only need to make finitely many choices after picking a basis. What's more, if the vector spaces are infinite dimensional, we're back to needing the axiom of choice.

Comment: You're right, it is a surprising—and useful—property of vector spaces! (and free constructions more generally)

Answer (score 3):

Consider III. Suppose it is true.
 $$w \in W \implies w=fg(w)=f(g(w))\\\implies w \in \;\;\text{range}\; f$$ Hence $ \text{range}\; f=W$, concluding $f$ is onto.

Is $f$ onto ?

Comment: We derived no contradiction but does this constitute as a proof?

Comment: I mean, If $f$ is onto, then III is true and conversely if III is true then $f$ must be onto

Comment: I see now. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I learn this result in Axler's linear algebra. In that book, Axler state this as a  exercise, namely, " If $T:V \to W$ is a linear map, then $T$ is onto $\iff$ there exists a linear map $S:W \to V$ such that $TS=I_W$"

Comment: something something ...every epimorphism in the category of $k$-vector spaces splits...

Comment: @RyleeLyman: Yes!...I agree.....

Answer (score -2):

For sure the I. it's false infact V could be $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ and $f(e_{n+1})=0$ and the hypothesis still true. The II. could be false infact if as in the first example $f(e_{n+1})=0$ we have that $g(f(e_{n+1}))=g(0)=0$ so the rank of $g(f(v))$ is $n$ and not $n+1$. So the right one is the III. infact if you choose $g$ such that $g(f(e_n))=e_n$ we have that $f(g(v))$ on $W$ in the base ${f(e_1),f(e_2),...,f(e_n)}$ is the identity.

If the answer it's wrong i will fix it tomorrow.

Comment: the assumption is that the $f(e_k)$ form a basis for $W$, so none of them are zero.

Comment: that's false because no one says that the dimension of V is n (look for example at the point I), so the first n $f(e_k)$ are a basis the rest could be everything.

Comment: Oh I see. You aren't wrong, but your explanation is confusing: the statement of the theorem doesn't mention any $e_k$ past $n$. In fact, *a priori* one might think the $e_k$ could be a linearly dependent set in $V$, so it's not clear how one could complete them to a basis. Of course our assumption implies that this is possible, but you need to tell us what you are assuming.